# Django request.post without waiting for response

Tags: django, python-requests

I have a Django server that communicates with a NodeJS server on another address (`REMOTE_SOCKET_ADDRESS`).

In Django, I have a line of code that goes like this:

`requests.post(settings.REMOTE_SOCKET_ADDRESS, params=query_params)`

I would like my Django server **to not wait for the response from the NodeJS server** before proceeding with the code. Just send the POST and go on, so that even if NodeJS needs 10 minutes to do whatever it is doing, it won't affect the Django Server.

How can I achieve this "fire and forget" behavior?

Additional info: I am on a shared hosting, so I cannot use workers.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using the `requests-futures` package: https://github.com/ross/requests-futures